# 'o' = 'u' + 6, shouldn't this be 'o' = 'u' - 6? Also doesn't arrays hold the value 0 for default?

Tags: c, linux

I'm am really confused. In ASCII `'a'` has the lowest value and `'z'` the biggest of lowercase letter. But why is `'o' = 'u' + 6`?

Say for instance I have

```
char array[100] = "errur";
char *ptr = array;
```

then I need to do

```
ptr[3] -= 6; // this
ptr[3] += 6; // not this
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

Also doesn't array initialized with zero by default? So that for `int array[10];` the element `array[9]` initially holds the value 0?

---

Lastly, when I run `&` in shell, is the command job the only way to list the working events?

Comment: I tried ptr[3] += 6, and the result was err{r.

Comment: Hello. These should be separate questions.

Comment: `ptr[3]` started out as `'u'`. You subtracted 6 and got `'o'`. It's all perfectly consistent. `'o' == 'u' - 6`. I've edited the comments in your code to make it clearer what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

In ASCII `'u'` has the value `117`, `'o'` has the value `111` so you have to substract `6` from `'u'` to get to `'o'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char array[100] = "errur";
    array[3] -= 6;
    printf("%s\n", array);
}
```

---

> Also doesn't array initialized with zero by default? So that for `int array[10];` the element `array[9]` initially holds the value 0?

No. Automatic variables have indeterminate values if you don't initialize them. `static` variables automatically get initialized with `0` of the appropriate type.

When you ommit initializers in an array definition those elements get set to zero:

```
int foo[3] = { 0 };     // foo[0] = 0, foo[1] = 0, foo[2] = 0
int bar[3] = { 1, 2 };  // bar[0] = 1, bar[1] = 2, bar[2] = 0
```